# Regex format for validation

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate below format in regex but I am not successful.

I have tried below regex

`"^[0-9]{1,6}X{1}$"`

`"^[0-9]{1,6}X$"`

It doesn't satisfy all conditions.

Required Format:

1. 12345 (only number is correct)
2. 2753XX (number with X is correct but X must be after number)
3. 542XXX45 (this format is not correct because X is between the number).
4. 4654abc ( this format is not correct because it is alpha numeric)

So I need a regex format for

1. String starts with number
2. String starts with number and end with X only
3. Max length of the string is 6 including X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed making the `X` *optional*.
Do this:

`^[0-9]{1,6}X*$ /gm`

This will mean text starting with one to six digits, ending in zero or more `X`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c19NZX/1)

For case-insensitivity, use the `/i` flag:

`^[0-9]{1,6}X*$ /gmi`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c19NZX/2)

Alternatively, you can also use a character set with both small and capital letters:

`^[0-9]{1,6}[Xx]*$ /gm`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c19NZX/3)

A *positive lookahead* will restrict the maximum length as desired:

`^(?=.{1,6}$)[0-9]*[Xx]*$ /gm`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c19NZX/5)

Comment: But I need validation for small 'x' and capital 'X'. Above regex work only for capital X

Comment: I changed it to ^[0-9]{1,6}X*x*$ it works for both but need the total string length to 6 now it's only work for Max number length to 6

Comment: @pranab So you want the number of `X` to also be limited to 6 max?

Comment: @pranab I suggest you edit your question to add these requirements. Comments section is not meant for this purpose.

Comment: No, need total string length to 6 including x

Answer (score 3):

Try the following pattern:

```
^(?=.{1,6}$)[0-9]{1,6}X*$
```

Here is an explanation of the pattern:

```
^                from the start of the string
    (?=.{1,6}$)  assert that the total length is at least 1 and at most 6
    [0-9]        then match 1 to 6 digits
    X*           followed by optional X
$                end of string
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Could you please add the total string length to 6 now it works for Max number length to 6

Comment: @pranab I edited my answer by adding a positive lookahead which asserts that the total length cannot exceed 6.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You missed anchoring the lookahead with `$`

Answer (score 0):

For validation, maybe limiting the number of X would be fine, such as with:

```
^[0-9]{1,6}X{0,6}$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/zPDPaN/1/)

or:

```
^(?:\dX{5}|\d{2}X{4}|\d{3}X{3}|\d{4}X{2}|\d{5}X|\d{6})$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/imtrok/1/)

Comment: why `X{0,6}` there isn't any upper limit defined for string length or for `X`